# Commandbutton Link to Visualforce Page Giving "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field"

Tags: visualforce, soql, redirect

I have a strange Visualforce problem: a commandbutton throws a "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field", but the same URL works as a straight-up link.

Markup is

```
<apex:commandbutton value="TMC Member Checklist" action="/apex/MemberFileChecklist?id={!Contact.id}" />
```

vs.

```
<a href="/apex/MemberFileChecklist?id={!Contact.id}">Member File Checklist</a>
```

Does anyone know why the link would work and the command button throw an error? Both are links to the same Visualforce page.

Comment: What is the full error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field _____ what field name does it point to? In your VF page controller is there a List of something you query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commandButton's attribute `action` is not to use as forwarding element. Here some info from the docs:

> The action method invoked by the AJAX request to the server. Use merge-field syntax ***to  reference the method***. For example,
>   action="{!save}" references the save method in the controller.

[Read the full doc here.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

If you want to redirect the user to another page just create a `PageReference` apex method for that and reference it in the command button:

```
public PageReference redirectUser(){
    PageReference ref = new PageReference('/apex/MemberFileChecklist?id=' + contact.id);
    return ref;
}

<apex:commandbutton value="TMC Member Checklist" action="{!redirectUser}"/>
```

[More info about PageReference.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm)

Alternatively, you can use `onclick` attribute and redirect with some javascript (if you don't want to create extra apex method). In this case you dont't need the action anymore:

```
<apex:commandbutton value="TMC Member Checklist" 
                    onclick="window.location='/apex/MemberFileChecklist?id={!Contact.id}'; return false;"/>
```

Comment: The onclick javascript works a treat. Thanks for the suggestion.